# MS-Access: input Quarter-of-year data

Tags: forms, date, datetime, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Basically I need to allow user input data in a `Qq/yy` or `Qq/yyyy` format (i.e. "Q4/2015" where "Q4" means last quarter or year 2015 - not Month 4).

I know I can take a `DateTime` value and format it with `Format()` but **this is not** what I need.

I need to provide user a form with an input control where he/she can type data in the above format and have this value stored in a database such a way that I can later perform reports and comparisons (like select all quarters from Q2/2015 to Q1/2016).

So I have two problems.

1. Input control.
2. Data type on my database.

If I simply take a `text` field in my table and set the input mask to `Q0/0099` I will have problems with my queries since I will not be able to compare records with `<` and `>`.

If I take a numeric or date field, I don´t know how to properly set a working input mask to set the input the way I need.

Any hints, please?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a DateTime value for later to make calculations and comparisons.

You can have two juxtaposed textboxes holding quarter and year, then use DateSerial:

```
Me!Date.Value = DateSerial(Nz(Me!Year.Value, Year(Date)), (Val(Right(Nz(Me!Quarter.Value, Format(Date, "q")), 1)) - 1) * 3 + 1, 1)
```

You can apply inputmasks as well, but many users dislike these.

To display the date as `Q4/2015`, set the Format property: `\Qq\/yyyy`

or use `=Format(Me!Date, "\Qq\/yyyy")` - or just the quarter or year part.